# Smallest triangle-free graph with chromatic number 5

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-colorings, extremal-graph-theory

The Grötzsch graph is triangle-free and has chromatic number 4. At 11 vertices it is the (unique) smallest graph with these properties.

What is the smallest number of vertices needed for a triangle-free graph with chromatic number 5? The Mycielskian of the Grötzsch graph has 23 vertices, so it's not larger than that.

There are far too many triangle-free connected graphs for enumeration to be a viable strategy. This question may well be unsolved; if so, I'd love a citation saying as much (if such exists).

Reed's conjecture implies that any such graph has max degree $\Delta\ge6.$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

22 vertices, there are 80 of them.

Jensen and Royle, Small graphs with chromatic number 5 : a computer search
Journal of Graph Theory, 1995.

Comment: Volume 19, Issue 1, January 1995, pp 107-116.

Comment: Note: The paper finds 80 graphs but doesn’t claim completeness.

Comment: I’ve redone it recently and confirmed that 80 is correct (should have said that in original answer, but can’t type well on small screen).

Comment: @GordonRoyle Do you mind if I quote you on that?

Comment: @Charles, feel free to quote me.

Comment: @GordonRoyle https://oeis.org/A292528